# How to identify expected time of a task

Tags: c#, task

I am about to create an application in c#.
In this application i have to show the user a dashboard on which user will see information about the task (like taskname, start time, last run time, status etc.)

My question is that how to identify that how long a task will take to complete?

My approach is to keep historical information of the task and based on this information, identify the expected time.

This approach is a bit clumsy.

Please suggest me if there is any better approach to identify the expected time of a task.

Comment: Historical information will be the best estimate. I think you will not get a good estimate analytically.

Comment: Historic recording of a task is probably the best way to go. You can always retun an `AVG(TimeTake)` back to the client with more detailed information later.

Comment: Historical data is a good way. Think about using an event store.

Comment: What is the task doing? How do tasks differ from another and how can you identify differences?
In case you are transfering data (writing files, ethernet transfer,..) and you know the pending ammount of data to transfer + average transfer speed, you can compute an estimation (pending size / (bytes per second) = seconds it will take)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement. If you only save the elapsed time, it will lose its value when user upgrade/downgrade the hardware. On the other hand, you could create a centralized service for every user to upload the spec (hardware, OS version etc) and elapsed time. Then you have a database. When user starts a new task, he can ask the service "What is the average elapsed time of this task on a PC with this CPU and that amount of memory and what is the maximum and minimum elapsed time among all users etc.?" Of course this approach is more complicated and may not fit your need.

Comment: this approach is a bit difficult. I am giving more explanation: My tasks are 1. read a file (csv/xls/txt) 2. Save data of file in database 3. show data on UI. I want a dashboard where user should see expected time for these tasks.

Comment: I also want to know how executable applications identify expected time whenever we install an application. e.g: whenever we install window/ms-office etc.